# uploading files with jquery $.ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I desire to upload files asynchronous when the user select a file in a input file, with $.ajax. But the php that recive the call return index undefined.
The jquery code is the next:

```
$("#urlimatge").change(function(){
            var filename = $("#urlimatge").val();
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "utils/uploadtempimg.php",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                data: {'urlimatge' : filename },
                success: function(response){
                     alert(response);
                }
            }); 

        });
```

and the php that recibe the call:

```
$image =  new gestorimatges();
$target_path = $image->uploadTemp($_FILES['urlimatge']['name'],$_FILES['urlimatge']['tmp_name']);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upload files with AJAX, but you can use an `iframe` so you don't have to refresh the current page.

Many people go strait to plugins but you can do this yourself pretty easily, and with all the functionality of an AJAX request.

Instead of using an AJAX function, have a form submit to a hidden `iframe` that has a `load` event handler attached to it so when the form is submitted, you have a callback function that actually includes the server response (the HTML of the `iframe` after it loads).

Example:

HTML --

```
<form action="..." method="post" encrypt="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" target="workFrame" >
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<iframe id="workFrame" src="about:blank" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

JS --

```
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function () {
        //check if the form submission is valid, if so just let it submit
        //otherwise you could call `return false;` to stop the submission
    });

    $('#workFrame').on('load', function () {

        //get the response from the server
        var response = $(this).contents().find('body').html();

        //you can now access the server response in the `response` variable
        //this is the same as the success callback for a jQuery AJAX request
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks I used a similar solution with an iframe. I call the iframe and modify the value of action with jquery.

Comment: following is not working for me: I am using mulit-file uploader to select multiple files. files are sent via the form only. It now opens a new "Tab" in my firefox browser....


 <FORM id="testajax_fileupload"
  style="display: inline;"
  METHOD="POST"
  ACTION="/cgi-bin/testajax_fileupload.pl"
  ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"
  target="iworkFrame"
  >
  <INPUT TYPE="file" class="multi" accept="gif|jpg" NAME="uploadedfile" SIZE="42"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
 </FORM>

Comment: <iframe id="iworkFrame" src="about:blank" style="display:none;"></iframe>


___Javascript is:____
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#iworkFrame").on('load', function () {
         var response = $(this).contents().find('body').html();
  alert("uploaded following:\n"+response);

    });

});

____objective is____1. another problem, the alert shows up on page load. i thought it will only show on response on form submission....
2. I am trying to not to open a new window or tab on file upload....

Comment: @rajeev Your code is hard to read as comments, I suggest creating a question with your issue.

Comment: @Jasper, hi, won't the page show a loading symbol in the tab when uploading through `iFrame`, like here: http://demos.9lessons.info/progress/index.php?success ? Whereas the image upload to the wall in Facebook does it without showing any loading symbol in the tab.

Comment: @Cupidvogel I'd think that depends on the browser but I'd expect there to be a loading spinner since you're loading a page in an iframe. There is a way to upload files via AJAX with XHR2 (and the `FormData` object). Here is browser support for XHR2: http://caniuse.com/#search=xhr2

Answer (score 3):

you cannot pass the $_FILE from AJAX to PHP.

I would suggest use a [plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

It will make your life easier :) [Here is a video tutorial to help too](http://youtu.be/-PpCwkjsxF4)

Comment: ok thanks, Could I pass enough parameters for to upload the file, for exemple the name or the url? I will try the plugin thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you can pass extra parameters in and everything, you just add in params: {anything: 'youwant'}

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna use tools like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for that.

Comment: Flash... just no reason to make people support Flash to use your form which is how Uploadify works.

Comment: There are many other tools which dont use flash.. check this.. http://superdit.com/2010/06/29/10-jquery-ajax-file-uploader-plugins/