# Keeping browser HTML form validation when submitting with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to keep the default HTML validation if submitting via Javascript?

What I mean is that, if I submit a form using this JS method:

```
document.getElementById("mc-embedded-subscribe-form").submit();
```

How do I keep the defualt error messages thrown by the browser?

[image]

One workaround I thought of is using this:

```
<form onSubmit="return somefunction()">
```

But because the API returns the success inside a closure function, I can't use this method.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep the error messages"? What's the desired effect?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat I assume he wants them to still appear/work.

Comment: What API returns the result inside a closure function?  And how does that prevent you from determining the result from within the `onsubmit` event handler?  It shouldn't, just use the API from within the `onsubmit` event handler, too.

Comment: Could you programmatically click on the submit button? Maybe that would do the same validation process it usually does.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 has also specified a JS API that you can use to interact with forms/elements in regard to their validation status: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api

So the easiest way to achieve this would be to call the [checkValidity](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-checkvalidity) method of your form, and only submit it when this returns true.

Something like this:

```
function submitIfValid() {
  var form = document.getElementById("mc-embedded-subscribe-form");
  if(form.checkValidity()) {
    form.submit();
  }
  else {
    //
  }
}
```

and then you would just call that function when you want to trigger form submission.

Answer (score 2):

according to my understanding of your question, html validation is not enough to halt submission, you have to validate required inputs in javascript too before submitting.

e.g

```
if (!empty(username)) {
    document.getElementById("mc-embedded-subscribe-form").submit();
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is my fallback plan. I was trying to find a way to keep the HTML validation but if I can't this might have to do. Thanks for the input! :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `form.submit()` ever.  Do it properly (`onsubmit`), or use `click()` on the submit button.

## Doing it properly...

I can't think of a good reason to automatically submit a visible form.  To submit data without user-interaction use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

A form is submitted by user interaction (e.g. pressing its submit button), so there is no need to use JavaScript to submit a form.  It is more likely that you need JavaScript to [prevent a form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248936), by returning `false` in the `onsubmit` event handler.

## ...or use `click()`

To *programatically* invoke HTML5 validation (and also any JavaScript `onsubmit` event handlers attached to the form), you can call the `click()` function of a submit button that belongs to the form.

If the form has no submit button, you can create a temporary one:

```
var form = document.getElementById("mc-embedded-subscribe-form");
var button = document.createElement('input');
button.type = 'submit';
button.style.display = 'none';
form.appendChild(button);
button.click();
```

Forms with multiple submit buttons should each have `name` attributes so the server can detect which button the user clicked.  You can 'click' these buttons using `form.buttonName.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

### `form` attribute

this solution avoids javascript, let's say that `#my-btn` is a button outside the form `#mc-embedded-subscribe-form`, you could just set on it

```html
<button id="my-btn" type="submit" form="mc-embedded-subscribe-form">Go!</button>
```

### `requestSubmit()`

with vanilla javascript you could call [`requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit)

```js
const form = document.getElementById('mc-embedded-subscribe-form');
form.requestSubmit();
```

### the hackish solution

you could put an hidden submit button in the form and then trigger the `click` event on it

```html
<form id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form">
    <button id="real-btn" type="submit" style="visibility: hidden"></button>
</form>

<button id="my-btn">Go!</button>
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('my-btn');
const btn_real = document.getElementById('real-btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    btn_real.click();
});
```